# A basic question on the Del symbol / gradient

Tags: calculus, vectors

I have a very basic question regarding the $\nabla$ (Del) symbol / gradient on a field (which I have called f). I have seen two definitions of this symbol:

1. $\nabla f = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial z})$
2. $\nabla f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \hat{\imath} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \hat{\jmath} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \hat{k}$ (where $\hat{\imath}$, $\hat{\jmath}$ and $\hat{k}$ are unit vectors)

Are (1) and (2) basically the same thing? If so, how do you get from (2) to (1)?

Many thanks!

Comment: This is just definitional.  In $\Bbb R^3$, $\hat i = (1,0,0)$, etc.

Comment: BTW, that's not the definition.  The definition of the gradient is $v\cdot \nabla f = D_v f, \forall v$.

Comment: @Bye_World I must really not understand all this! I thought that was the divergence?

Comment: Take a look at the definition.  $\nabla f$ has to be a vector to be able to apply the dot product to it.  So it couldn't be a definition of the divergence (which is a scalar quantity).

Comment: Sorry I meant that ∇f is the gradient and v⋅∇f is the divergence? Please excuse my ignorance - I have only started trying to learn vector calculus today!

Comment: No.  The divergence, often denoted $\nabla \cdot f$ is defined as $$(\nabla \cdot f)(x) = \lim_{|V|\to 0} \frac{1}{|V|}\int_{\partial V} f\cdot \hat n\ dS$$ where $V$ is a volume that contains the point $x$.  In Cartesian coordinates, this reduces to $$\nabla \cdot f = \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f_3}{\partial z}$$

Comment: Oh, OK - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they're the same.  In the first definition, you're writing the gradient in standard 3D coordinate notation $(a,b,c)$.  In vector algebra/calculus, you start to think about these three numbers as being *components* of a vector with respect to some *basis* (these are linear algebra terms).  The "standard basis" of 3D vector calculus consists of the three vectors

$$
\hat{\boldsymbol{\imath}} = \left[\begin{array}{c} 1\\0\\0\end{array}\right],\quad \hat{\boldsymbol{\jmath}} = \left[\begin{array}{c} 0\\1\\0\end{array}\right],\quad 
\hat{\boldsymbol{k}} = \left[\begin{array}{c} 0\\0\\1\end{array}\right]
$$  Then, the coordinates $(a,b,c)$ correspond to a column vector as follows:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c} a\\b\\c\end{array}\right] = a\left[\begin{array}{c} 1\\0\\0\end{array}\right] + b\left[\begin{array}{c} 0\\1\\0\end{array}\right]+c\left[\begin{array}{c} 0\\0\\1\end{array}\right] = a \hat{\boldsymbol{\imath}} +b\hat{\boldsymbol{\jmath}} + c\hat{\boldsymbol{k}} 
$$  Thinking of the gradient as a column vector, you'll see why they're the same!

Answer (score 2):

You have already gotten good explanation by @icarays1 on the notation so I'll skip that part.

---

$\nabla$ is an operator. It contains spatial derivatives with respect to all basis vectors. If operating on a scalar valued function it creates a vector.

The **divergence of a vector field** is the *inner product* between the nabla operator and a vector valued function:

$$\nabla \cdot {\bf v} = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}\frac{d}{dx}&\frac{d}{dy}&\frac{d}{dz}\end{array}\right){\bf v} = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}\frac{d}{dx}&\frac{d}{dy}&\frac{d}{dz}\end{array}\right)  \left(\begin{array}{c}{v_x}\\v_y\\v_z\end{array}\right) = \sum_{k \in \{x,y,z\}}\frac{d(v_k)}{d_k}$$

The **gradient of a scalar field** is the *outer product* between the nabla operator and a scalar valued function:

$$\nabla f = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}\frac{d}{dx}\\\frac{d}{dy}\\\frac{d}{dz}\end{array}\right)f =  \left(\begin{array}{ccc}\frac{d(f)}{dx}\\\frac{d(f)}{dy}\\\frac{d(f)}{dz}\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: For scalar-valued $f$, $\nabla f = J_f^T$, and for vector-valued ${\bf v} $, $\nabla \cdot {\bf v}  = \text{trace } J_{\bf v}$, where $J$ is the Jacobian. Is that correct?

Comment: @Max yes, Jacobian is a tensor outer product (expansion) with $\nabla$ : numbers of indices increase. Likewise divergence is example of a tensor inner product (contraction) : numbers of indices lower.